# ruby tutorial Listing 10.61: Action-level tests for admin access control failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following Rails Tutorial from Michael Hartl, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users.

I am having an error to pass one of the action level tests for admin access control test.

The test failed is as follows:

```
def setup
    @user       = users(:jessie) #admin
    @other_user = users(:brenda) #non_admin
end



test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
     delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
end
```

The error that the terminal gives me is :

FAIL["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin", UsersControllerTest, 1.6799899999750778]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin#UsersControllerTest (1.68s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to root_url but was a redirect to login_url.
        Expected root_url to be === login_url.
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:65:in `block in '

My users_controller.rb file is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user=User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user

    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index

    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  #Confirms a logged_in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the current user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    recirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  private


    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user

    def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

As I've been following the tutorial strictly and I am still very new to ruby on rails, it's very hard for me to identify where went wrong. I've been googling for solutions for a few hours, but in vain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you :)